# How to calculate partial $R^2$ in linear models?

Tags: r, regression, r-squared

I built a multi-variable linear model using the `lm()`.

How I'm looking for the partial R squared of every variable in the model,
 that is the variance explained by this variable and its proportion in the shared explained variance.

For example, using the "mtcars" data set from the `datasets` package:

```
require(datasets)
data(mtcars)
mdl<-lm(mpg~.,data=mtcars)
summary(mdl)
```

I get :

```
 Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
   -3.4506 -1.6044 -0.1196  1.2193  4.6271 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 12.30337   18.71788   0.657   0.5181  
cyl         -0.11144    1.04502  -0.107   0.9161  
disp         0.01334    0.01786   0.747   0.4635  
hp          -0.02148    0.02177  -0.987   0.3350  
drat         0.78711    1.63537   0.481   0.6353  
wt          -3.71530    1.89441  -1.961   0.0633 .
qsec         0.82104    0.73084   1.123   0.2739  
vs           0.31776    2.10451   0.151   0.8814  
am           2.52023    2.05665   1.225   0.2340  
gear         0.65541    1.49326   0.439   0.6652  
carb        -0.19942    0.82875  -0.241   0.8122  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.65 on 21 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.869, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8066 
F-statistic: 13.93 on 10 and 21 DF,  p-value: 3.793e-07
```

So the adjusted $R^2$ for the whole model is $0.8066$, but I'm looking for the $R^2$ squared of every variable. Is there a function in R that does that?

Comment: You might wanna have a look at the Partial R².
[rddr.it/cran/ppcor](https://rdrr.io/cran/ppcor/man/pcor.html)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the [relaimpo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relaimpo/index.html) package will give you a measure of the relative importance of each coefficient, which seems to be what you are after. The lmg measure provided by using calc.relimp(mdl) is not $R^2$ but closely related one.

From help("calc.relimp"):

*lmg is the R^2 contribution averaged over orderings among regressors, cf. e.g. Lindeman, Merenda and Gold 1980, p.119ff or Chevan and Sutherland (1991).*

```
> calc.relimp(mdl)
Relative importance metrics: 

        lmg
cyl  0.12134515
disp 0.12023870
hp   0.10698627
drat 0.07327014
wt   0.15828880
qsec 0.03827073
vs   0.06588052
am   0.07337623
gear 0.04409332
carb 0.06726591
```